# How to compare filenames with OS-specific rules?

Tags: python, filenames

Different operating systems have different rules for determining if two file names match or not.  For example, comparing `'abc'` to `'ABC.'` would be the same file under Windows but completely different files under Linux.  Is there a built in function to compare those names?

Failing that, is there a way to convert any arbitrary file name to its canonical representation for the OS?

Comment: It's even worse. On Unix it's filesystem-specific, you can have case-sensitive and case-insensitive filesystems. E.g. if you mount a Windows fileserver.

Comment: @Barmar yes I knew about that complication but thought that was just too much to ask.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870041/check-if-file-system-is-case-insensitive-in-python